# new multisite, old db

Tags: multisite, database, mysql, migration

I'm trying to get my old posts from a WP install that was in a sub-directory on my site, into a new Multisite install on a new host.

The new install is doing what it should. the problem is the posts are in a database with a different table prefix. i'll admit that i didn't think it would be this difficult.

but i need it to either pull from the correct prefix `wed_` not `wp_2_`

*or*

replace all the data in `wp_2_` with the data from `wed_`

thanks.

**ANSWER**

after some poking around some mysql websites, i found that find/replace isn't really straight forward.

lets assume that the database table prefixes in question are `new_` and `old_` and that i want to replace `new` with `old`

myphpadmin has an option of **change prefix**,

here are the steps i did to correct my issue.

1. export the sql databases to my desktop as a backup.
2. change `new_` to `bak_new_`
3. change `old_` to `new_`

   - since nothing else has changed wordpress is still pulling from the `new_` tables, but has `old_`'s data.
   - this works! but no images.
4. export the new `new_` to the desktop.
5. open in a text editor and find/replace all the old urls that should point to your images to your new url.

   - when using multisite installs the upload folder has new subfolders.

     - new path: `http://example.com/wedding/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2014/06/program03.jpg`
     - old path: `http://example.com/wedding/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/program03.jpg`
   - note the added `sites/2` in the new path.
   - save

In myphpadmin

1. select all the `new_` tables and drop them.

   - this deletes them, after giving a warning that asks if you *really* want to do this. click yes.
2. import the file with the replaced urls with the same `new_` prefix.

**done**

upload all the images to the new path of the server and verify that everything works. then delete the `bak_new_` tables since they're useless now. now all the old data from my
old/incorrectly install site works on the new multisite install.

Comment: **HUZZAH** I figured it out after some experimenting and intentionally breaking my site. I'll post my answer soon for future reference.

Comment: Easiest method for future reference... export the old site to WP format and import as a site on the new multi-site install.